# When to use Union in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

With Union, in what real world situation would you use it?  Because it doesn't make sense to me to use union on two select queries from two tables that have different column purposes/meanings.  For example:

table person:

```
id   name    age

1    mark    23
2    shawn   18
```

table addresses:

```
id   personID   address

1      1        some address
2      2        another random address
```

Based on the above tables, in what way or for any reason would you use a Union query?

**EDIT**

Basically my understanding is you use UNIONs when working on similar information from different tables into one table for efficiency purposes, rather always querying separately or using JOINs to work on the similar information.

**EDIT**

Or also when design of tables(DB) is not well thought out.  Because theres nothing stopping anyone from designing a db not perfect because of time constraints AND when you don't know full extent of final design for table(s).

Comment: Whats wrong with asking a question of what situation to use UNION?  I don't understand how thats against guidlines...

Comment: @Shadow, This is a legitimate question. If you don't want to answer it, move along.

Comment: Most "real world" situations are poorly designed schemas and OR-condition optimisations. (IMHO)

Comment: When the data can't be retrieved rationally using `JOIN` or any means, yet you still want to pull the data up in a single query.

Comment: @BillKarwin it is a legitimate question if it is asked in the right way. This question is very badly written and in its original version when I made my commen, it was unclear to me what the OP was after. It is still not clear to me what's the purpose of the sample data, for which union cannot be used. The tone of the question is prejudiced. Judging by the down and close votes, there are others who share similar thoughts about this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example is in the case of a non-normalized table that you want to normalize for a given reason (but not change the original table).  Let's say you have a table called Loan_Disbursements with the following attributes:

```
LoanID, Disbursement_Date, Disbursement_Amount, Refund_Date, Refund_Amount
```

You want to normalize this to the following (I know, not the best names):

```
LoanID, Activity_Date, Activity_Amount, Activity_Name
```

The code would look something like this:

```
SELECT LoanID, Disbursement_Date AS Activity_Date, Disbursement_Amount AS Activity_Amount, 'Disbursement' AS Activity_Name
FROM Loan_Disbursements

UNION ALL

SELECT LoanID, Refund_Date AS Activity_Date, Refund_Amount AS Activity_Amount, 'Refund' AS Activity_Name
FROM Loan_Disbursements
```

Of course, there are other ways to achieve this same thing (like using two derived tables) in one SQL statement.  However, you will also need to evaluate the query plan and if there is a difference in performance.

As a side note, if you are asking, "in a perfect world", where would this be used - that is really like asking, "in a perfect world", why would you need a spare tire.  In almost twenty years, I have yet to find this perfect world.  But, that's part of the fun really.

I hope that helps.

Cheers!

Comment: exactly, unions are for efficiency purposes.  Because say you have similar information from multiple tables and have several queries to do on that similar information, wouldn't it be more efficient to do a union for the similar information, and from then on do queries on it VS for each of those queries always doing a JOIN of some sort?

Comment: But ya your right, its because theres never enough time or need to design a perfect db just as there is for anything, in those cases you need backup option.