# Mysql SELECT values from two columns as individual entries

Tags: mysql

I am working on a migration script and I need to bring all the employee telephone numbers, which are now stored in the employee table, as individual entries in my select.

I have tried using right joins, even INNER JOIN, but I am afraid that this is a job for UNION which unfortunately I cannot fully grasp.

The table looks something like this:

[image]

and the select should bring data like this

[image]

or even better, like this:

[image]

Comment: This answer will help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754583/3710053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `employee_id`, 'landline' AS `type`, `landline`  AS `number` FROM `employee`
UNION ALL
SELECT `employee_id`, 'mobile'  AS `type`, `mobile`     AS `number` FROM `employee`
```